# What are the main feature you need to understand to be able to manage Ubuntu and Nginx

Tags: server, nginx

I recently started managing my own Ubuntu server and Nginx for HTTP purposes, but I often find confusing as to what parts belong to what server, ports, permissions etc.

I do understand Ubuntu is the actual sever and Nginx is just an HTTP server, what I don't know understand is what server manages what, for instance if you want to add a firewall to restrict the access to some ports or change file permissions of some files I'm always asking myself, is this Nginx or Ubuntu (I know in both of my examples here Ubuntu is the owner).

I know this question is so broad but I need to start somewhere asking dummy questions.

1. If you were to define the features/topics you MUST know in order to start understanding both environments what would those features were?
2. How would you describe each server?
3. Learn Ubuntu first and than Nginx or both at the same time?
4. Where would you start learning are there any good tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Server is an operating system that manages a lot of software. Each software has its own functionalities and nginx is just another software that you can install on your ubuntu server and that will add the functionality to send back the files its asked for. Ubuntu will have port(s) that will be associated with nginx (and on which nginx will be configured to listen) so that each times Ubuntu receives a request specifically adressed to that port it will say to nginx "hey, that IP said that to you" and nginx will respond "ok, answer that". Everything that is not related to what nginx should respond to a request over its configured ports is managed by another software (bind9 for DNS, iptables for firewall restrictions, ...)

---

1. You must know how to use SSH, and how to install/configure software using commands. Also, I would say that ports would be a very important thing to know about in order to set a HTTP server.
2. Ubuntu Server is just like your operating system but without all "useless" stuff that is only needed for the comfort of the user. nginx is a server that takes a request that is addressed to your ubuntu server on a port that is associated with nginx (HTTP(S) is often 80(443)) and returns the file that was asked in the request. It may redirect the request to other software that will process the file and send back the response to nginx that will send it back to you
3. I would say Ubuntu first and then nginx as you will need to install/configure Ubuntu and then configure/install nginx from Ubuntu
4. There are plenty of good tutorials out there. [This one](https://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-nginx-bind-mysql-php-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig3) seems to be a good one, it will teach you to install a server from scratch and to install services such as mail server (postfix/dovecot), http server (nginx/apache) and a DNS server (bind). It may be a too complete tutorial according to your needs but it may also be a good way to understand both environments. Also, software documentation will be your best friend in case of problems, [here is the nginx one](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your first statement answered some other inquiries I had in regard how the communication happens between the two, it looks like Ubuntu is the first one to be exposed in any communication to the outside world and then redirects it to the most appropriate piece of software, on this case Nginx . It looks like I will need to master ports in Ubuntu, I will start with that. Thanks again.